# How do use rand crate for random sampling on my type (i.e. impl Distribution<Point> for an arbitrary distributions, where Point is my type)

Tags: random, rust, traits

I have defined a type for 2D points:

```
struct Point(f64, f64)
```

I would like to be able to generate random points using `rand` crate. To avoid manually implementing `Distribution<Point>` for all the distributions in the `rand` crate, I tried to implement this trait for all distributions that implement `Distribution<f64>`.

```
impl<D: Distribution<f64>> Distribution<Point> for D {
    fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Point {
        Point(self.sample(rng), self.sample(rng))
    }
}
```

However, I get an error saying that there are conflicting implementations for the type `&_`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The error message contains a lot of valuable information. Please read it, and include the full error message in your question so we can read it, too.

Comment: That said, most distributions don't make two much sense if implemented this way. For example a normal distribution should be extended in a rotationally symmetric way to a point, not by simply using a normal distribution in each of the coordinates. So I think what you are trying to do doesn't make much sense to begin with.

Comment: @SvenMarnach actually you get the bidimensional normal distribution by simply sampling two monodimensional normal distributions. But you're right that this doesn't make sense for a lot of other distributions.

Comment: @Jmb You are right, I noticed later that I chose exactly the one example where it happens to work. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I already understand why the error happens. I'm interested in whether it's possible to only implement this trait only for distributions that are not references.

Comment: There isn't a way of specifying negative trait bounds to do this. You could have a dummy trait which does nothing, have an empty impl on each of the distros you want, and then add that to the Trait bound in the impl. You only have to implement the function once, but that doesn't get around having to explicitly reference all the distributions.